# How To Account For Nulls When Pattern matching using Grok?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, logstash-grok

I am trying to read log data in `Apache NiFi` using `grok` but not able to fetch desired output. Here is my sample data:

```
[2019-07-16 22:20:16] local.INFO: news.index {"mobile":"959404576540","message":Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ATU-L42 Build/HUAWEIATU-L42; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/66.0.3359.126 Mobile Safari/537.36 a/2.7.0}
```

I tried with following expression but didn't worked for me.

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD}%{JAVACLASS}: %{JAVACLASS} {%{QS}:%{QS},%{QS}:%{QS}}
```

How can I extract `2019-07-16 22:20:16`, `959404576540`, `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; ATU-L42 Build/HUAWEIATU-L42; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/66.0.3359.126 Mobile Safari/537.36 a/2.7.0` from the above data?

**Edit:**

@Emma Your answer is working but if my data contains any null values it is not working. For example:

```
[2019-07-16 22:20:16] local.INFO: news.index {"mobile":"8765453673","message":null}
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression,

```
\[([^]]+?)\](.*?)"mobile":"\s*(\d+)\s*"\s*,\s*"message"\s*:\s*([^}]*?)\s*\}
```

for instance might be a start to extract those data.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ug9TAO/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Comment: it works well but if my data contains any null it is not working.. i am updating my question. please have a look.